# Make all absolute links relative

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

I am looking for a regex solution for this problem. It can be a multiple step solution if this makes things easier. Important notice: The test string is just a snippet of a complete HTML DOM and only images should get addressed by this and any other URL should be left alone.

Here's an image:

```
<img 
src="https://www.example.com/de/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/2017/03/image.jpg"
data-srcset="
 https://www.example.com/de/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/2017/03/img1.jpg 507w,
 https://www.example.com/de/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/2017/03/img2.jpg 780w,
 https://www.example.com/de/wp-content/uploads/sites/74/2017/03/img3.jpg 950w"
data-sizes="
 (min-width: 80em) calc(0.5 * (100vw - (100vw- 57em))),
 (min-width: 48em) calc(0.5 * (100vw - 5em)),
 calc(100vw - 1em)"
alt="image" class="lazyload">
```

As a oneliner:

```
<img src="https://www.example.com/de/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/2017/03/image.jpg" data-srcset="https://www.example.com/de/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/2017/03/img1.jpg 507w, https://www.example.com/de/wp-content/uploads/sites/1/2017/03/img2.jpg 780w, https://www.example.com/de/wp-content/uploads/sites/74/2017/03/img3.jpg 950w" data-sizes="(min-width: 80em) calc(0.5 * (100vw - (100vw- 57em))), (min-width: 48em) calc(0.5 * (100vw - 5em)), calc(100vw - 1em)" alt="image" class="lazyload">
```

The desired result is that need to get rid of protocol, domain, and first directory - that is to say: everything in front of the /wp-content. The language I am doing this in is php.

For the src part I have

```
 preg_replace("/(<img.*?src=\")(.*?)(\/wp-content.*?\")(.*>)/", '"$1$3$4"', $string);
```

**The answer below is correct.** Most HTML documents should be able to load. Do yourself a favor and try to be as valid as possible, this is a good thing anyways. If you don't produce the HTML in question yourself, try to process it before you consume it.

For the data-srcset problem just parse that argument separately.

Compare your DOM before and after completely. The `@dom->saveHTML()` method makes closed tags which do not need to be closed, closed. Like `<meta arg="yada"/>` turns to `<meta arg="yada">` (closing backslash missing). Also see [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Comment: [That answer is for you](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732454/revisions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't.** Use a parser to analyze the DOM and apply the regex on the DOM elements/attributes directly.

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$images = $xpath->query("//img[contains(@src, 'wp-content')]");

$regex = '~^.+?(?=/wp-content/)~';
foreach($images as $img) {
    $img->setAttribute('src', 
        preg_replace($regex, 'https://anotherdomain.com', $img->getAttribute('src'))
    );
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

It has been answered a dozen times why it is not a good idea to parse HTML with regular expressions, one of the most favourite answers being this:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

---

However, if your HTML is not valid, you could use the following regex (in verbose mode):

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|<img)
(?s:.+?\bsrc=['"])\K
https?://.+?(?=/wp-content/)
```

See it [**working on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/9VsJQN/3).

Comment: Don't? Elaborate, please.

Comment: "Dozen times" ... for regular readers or those asking the right questions ;-) If I had stumbled upon this ... funny answer ;-) ...

Comment: @wloske: It is, indeed :)

Comment: Oh, did I mention your example does not work :-)

Basically because my HTML is not valid and I also can not guarantee it.

Comment: @wloske: Then see the updated answer at the bottom. Of course, it is possible to analyze HTML strings via regex though not advisable.

Comment: Thanks, @Jan, for this approach but it still does not tackle the main problem: The data-srcset part with an unknown number of absolute URLs separated by a comma.